# How can I do 'a' + 1 #=> 'b' in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm working on a project need this functionality very frequently

```
'b' + 1 #=> 'a' and 'b' - 1 #=> 'a'
```

Now my solution is very tedious :

```
str(unichr((ord('b')+ 1)))
```

is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about your requirements but if you have to do this a lot in your project, maybe it's better to convert all your characters to their ASCII values, then do all the math on ints and in the end convert the ints back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str(unichr(c))` can be replaced with just `chr(c)`.

Simplified version:

```
chr(ord('b') + 1)
```

Comment: And in python 3, you'll have to. :-)

Answer (score 5):

define your own function:

```
In [103]: def func(c,n):
    return chr(ord(c)+n)
   .....: 

In [105]: func('a',-1)
Out[105]: '`'

In [106]: func('b',-1)
Out[106]: 'a'

In [107]: func('c',2)
Out[107]: 'e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is strongly typed and considerer strings and ints are different, and won't convert one to another implicitly.

However, you code can probably be simplified to

```
chr(ord('b') + 1)
```

If you use it a lot, put it in a function, and don't worry about it any more :

```
def incr_char(c, n):
    return chr(ord(c) + n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.letters[string.letters.index('a')+1]
'b'
```

Just for Ashwini:

```
>>> string.letters[string.letters.index('a')-1]
'Z'
```

Comment: I am not sure, but as OP is using `ord()` so 'Z' might not be the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
class char(unicode):
    def __add__(self, x):
        return char(unichr(ord(self) + x))

print char('a') + 1 # b
```